# Programmatically Present Windows (Invoke Window Picker) in Compiz

Tags: compiz, application-development, programming, development, wmctrl

Is there a bash command to invoke what `Super+W` does in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

If you install `xte` (`sudo apt-get install xautomation`) you can simulate a <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> with the:

```
xte 'keydown Super_L' 'keydown w' 'keyup Super_L' 'keyup w'
```

If you want to *change* the key that activates the window spread the key is located at:

```
/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/scale/initiate-key
```

In dconf. Or you can use Unity Tweak Tool.